# A problem with my macro for partial application in Common Lisp

Tags: macros, common-lisp, currying

I am trying to make a macro to achieve partial application in Common Lisp. Here was my thought on how I would implement that in pseudocode:

```
If my argument list is null, return the function body
Otherwise, cons together "lambda" with the first argument with a recursive call to "partial-lambda" again

(lambda (x y z) (+ x y z) => (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (z) (+ x y z))))
```

Here's my code:

```lisp
(defmacro partial-lambda (params &rest body)
    (if (null params) body
        (lambda ((car params)) (partial-lambda (cdr params) body))))

(partial-lambda (x y z) (+ x y z))
```

Unfortunately, SBCL gives me this error:

```
; in: DEFMACRO PARTIAL-LAMBDA
;     (LAMBDA (CAR PARAMS) (PARTIAL-LAMBDA (CDR PARAMS) BODY))
; ==>
;   #'(LAMBDA (CAR PARAMS) (PARTIAL-LAMBDA (CDR PARAMS) BODY))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable CAR is defined but never used.

; file: /Users/caspianahlberg/Desktop/Programming/Lisp/partial_application.lisp
; in: DEFMACRO PARTIAL-LAMBDA
;     (PARTIAL-LAMBDA (CDR PARAMS) BODY)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::PARTIAL-LAMBDA
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     PARTIAL-LAMBDA
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions
STYLE-WARNING:
   PARTIAL-LAMBDA is being redefined as a macro when it was previously assumed to be a function.
```

Why does it complain about `car` never being used? I find that really confusing. Does anyone who is good with CL macros know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: FYI in Alexandria there is `curry`: https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defmacro partial-lambda (params &rest body)
    (if (null params) `(progn ,@body)
        `(lambda (,(car params)) (partial-lambda ,(cdr params) ,@body))))

CL-USER 43 > (partial-lambda (x y z) (+ x y z))
#<anonymous interpreted function 40300008DC>

CL-USER 44 > (funcall * 10)
#<anonymous interpreted function 403000094C>

CL-USER 45 > (funcall * 15)
#<anonymous interpreted function 40300009BC>

CL-USER 46 > (funcall * 3)
28
```

[Backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) is variant of [QUOTE](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm), which allow unquoting inside it. , is used, when you want unquote  something inside quoted section (that expression is replaced with value). And ,@ (unquote-splicing) unquotes something, replaces it and removes parentheses around that value. These operations are commonly used in Lisp macros.

**EDIT:** `(car body)` replaced with  `` `(progn ,@body) `` for handling inputs with more expressions in body: `(partial-lambda (x y z) (print 5)(+ x y z))`.

Answer (score 1):

**A syntax error**

> `(lambda ((car params)) (partial-lambda (cdr params) body))`

Common Lisp expects a list of parameters as the second element of a lambda form. A parameter is a symbol. The list of parameters is not evaluated.

Your code has a list `(car params)` as the first parameter. But Common Lisp expects a symbol.

**Your example also does not match the error you have shown.**

Probably you did:

```
(defmacro partial-lambda (params &rest body)
  (if (null params)
      body
      (lambda (car params) (partial-lambda (cdr params) body))))
```

But then you define a parameter list with the parameters `car` and `params`. That makes no sense. That's why th Lisp compiler complains that the variable `car` is unused.

**Macros operate on code**

Remember, your macro needs to return code. Code gets created with list operators or a backquote expression.

A backquote expression would look like this (see the answer from Martin Půda):

```
`(lambda (,(car params)) (partial-lambda ,(cdr params) ,@body))
```

The backquote allows selected parts of the list template to be evaluated. The *comma* evaluates and inserts the result. The *comma atsign* evaluates and splices the result list in.